# laravel installation of 5.1 LTS compared to 5.2 in their docs is identical

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1#installation

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
laravel new blog
```

ok cool, seems simple

now let's check out [how to install 5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2#installation)

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
laravel new blog
```

right, exactly the same. I guess the 5.1 installation is actually the 5.2 installation and their docs is buggy. That is, starting from the very very first step, the installation, already wrong.

I hoped I wouldn't have to start that way.

so i guess i need to use the composer install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation is up-to-date with current state when it was released. Probably nobody will update documentation for old releases unless serious changes were made.

To create Laravel 5.1 project you should use:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel name_of_your_project 5.1
```

And to create Laravel 5.2 project you should use:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel name_of_your_project 5.2
```

Comment: why not use that line in the installation then? because it has 3 more characters? is this a joke by taylor? The long term candidate should be easy to install, don't you think? when i try installing the LTS version, and i get STS, i will be surprised.

Comment: I guess this solution works, i have installed it with composer now already.